# Apply CIFilter to SKEffectNode on iOS7

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, cifilter

Using SpriteKit in Swift, I have this code inside my GameScene (a SKScene):

```
//Init function
let self.itemsLayer = SKNode()

let grayNode = SKEffectNode()
let grayFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir")
grayFilter.setDefaults()
grayNode.filter = grayFilter
grayNode.addChild(self.itemsLayer)

self.addChild(grayNode)
```

It is supposed to render the items I display into the itemsLayer in gray color (later in the code I add some SKSpriteNode with textures/images into the itemsLayer).

On iOS8, it works perfectly: I can see all my items being in gray.

But on iOS7, the SKSpriteNodes (my items on itemsLayer) are not displayed (as if hidden).

CIPhotoEffectNoir does exist in iOS7 according to the documentation and to `filterNamesInCategory("CICategoryColorEffect")`.

**Edit** : When I comment the filter lines, my itemsLayer is still hidden. When I convert `let grayNode` to a `SKNode`, it works back (but no effect is applied of course). The problem seems to come from the grayNode being a `SKEffectNode`

Comment: How are you running on iOS7, by setting the deployment target or by running on an earlier version of Xcode?

Comment: I tested on an iPhone 4S on iOS 7.1 and with simulators on 7.1 (I had to download 900Mo of simulator from Xcode because it only had iOS8.1). Deployment target is set to iOS7.1. Btw, I created the project for iOS8 first, then decided to support iOS7 too.

Comment: Are you seeing an error in the console window?

Comment: No error at all, the game runs perfectly, everything just seems hidden. I have the exact same code in iOS8 and iOS7. Updated the post with additional "debugging"

Comment: I'm getting the following error "[CIImage initWithTexture:size:flipped:colorSpace] requires an integral size!" when I run on the 4S sim running iOS 7, and the node is hidden. It works on iOS 8.

Comment: That's strange, I'm not having any error. Besides where would CIImage error come from as it is not explicitly declared ?

Comment: Oddly, the error went away after I created `itemsLayer` as an `SKSpriteNode` and it now works. I'm adding the default Spaceship sprites to that layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging, I realized that iOS7 doesn't render `SKEffectNode` the same way as iOS8 does.

In iOS7, adding a SKEffectNode to a bunch of `SKSpriteNode` layers will **not** put it automatically to the most front layer (which is the case with SKSpriteNode).

So I only needed to add the line :

```
grayNode.zPosition = 10 //Or any number > 1
```

Comment: Setting `skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false` in your view controller should work, as well.